# How load network video before navigation

Tags: flutter, video, navigation, video-player

I try to load the video before navigation and when I navigate the screen video can be loaded and played at that time

Answer (score 0):

You have two options here:

1. Using a caching system and fetching the content at any time before you navigate to that specific screen, so whenever you try to display it you get it from your caching system;
2. Fetching the content at any time before you navigate to that specific screen and passing it as parameter to the screen you are pushing to;